# Toad Movement Model Example

Tags: stochastic-processes

This model of toad movement is presented in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030438001630850X. I'm confused at to how the probabilities are set out and was wondering why if P(return) = $\sum_i p_{ret(i)}$ then why is $1 -p_{ret} = \prod (1-p_{ret(i)}) \neq 1 - \sum_i p_{ret(i)}$, since the events of returning to each specific site are mutually exclusive.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you are right. I hope the $p_{ret(i)}$ are small enough that it doesn't affect their results too much.

Comment: Yes, the way they've set up the no return probability and conditional probability below seem to contradict each other. It seems that they have treated the probability of return to each site separately from each other, which doesn't seem to make sense. The conditional probability is fine I think for selecting the return location, but the non return probability can't be right.

Comment: does the "return" in the conditional means return to a single site? or does it mean "return" regardless of how many sites?

Comment: It should mean return to any single site which is what a return event is.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get around why there is $1-p_{ret}$ in $(2)$. I suppose $p_{ret}$ is the probability of returning at all. So its supposed to be the probability of not returning at all.

---

Intuitively they aren't equal,$\prod(1-p_{ret(i)})\neq 1-\sum p_{ret(i)}$ since:

Not returning to any of the sites: $\prod(1-p_{ret(i)})$

Not returning to all of the sites (here the toad could return to just a few): $1-\sum p_{ret(i)}$

Hence,

$$1-\sum p_{ret(i)}>\prod(1-p_{ret(i)})$$

Comment: I'm not sure how not returning to any site is different from not returning to all sites, should they not be the same thing?

Comment: It means literally returning to all of the sites in the single event. The study talks about site fidelity so I thought one may become infidel and return to all of them on a single event.

Comment: No I believe it should really be that the toad only returns to a single refuge at a time since only one location is recorded per day. So the events of returning to each previous refuge should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: I guess this question is not gaining much answers. Try posting this at math.stackexchange.com instead